# JFreeChart Add Percentage to PieChart in JSP

Tags: jsp, jfreechart, pie-chart

This is my code for creating a PieChart in JSP.

```
Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection(); 

String strQuery = "SELECT keyword,count(*) from paper_keywords group by keyword";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
while(rs.next())
{ 
    pieDataset.setValue(rs.getString(1),rs.getInt(2));
}
rs.close();
preparedStatement.close();  

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart ("Popular Keywords", pieDataset, true,true,true);

try {
    final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo (new    StandardEntityCollection());


String test = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
final File file1 = new File(test+"chart/areachart.png");

ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 550, 400, info);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
out.println(e);
}
```

I will use it later in the jsp page:

```
<IMG SRC="../chart/areachart.png" >
```

How can I add the percentage at legend? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [`StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator.html) can do this.

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setLegendLabelGenerator(
    new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: First download jfreechart from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjfreechartjar.htm

Step 2: Include the jar file in build path

Step 3: Add following code

```
 PiePlot plot2 = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
       plot2.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieItemLabelGenerator(
                "{0} ({2})", NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(), NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()
            ));
```